# Tcl array syntax

Tags: tcl

I have this proc in some Tcl

```
proc AddType {type} {
    set map (...code to create the map here...)
    if {[info exists map("$type")]} {    
        set frame $map("$type")
    } else {
        set frame [MakeFrame]
    }
}
```

which works correctly.  Unfortunately, something in the middle of it "breaks" Notepad++'s syntax highlighting, such that it shows like this:

[image: screenshot showing syntax highlighting error]

If I change `$map("$type")` to `$map( "$type")` then all is happy in terms of the syntax highlighting:

[image: screenshot showing correct syntax highlighting]

however the Tcl then fails to load.  This is some legacy Tcl, and this proc is near the start of a pretty large file and all of the syntax highlighting is wrong from this point to the end of the file, so it's pretty irritating.

Is there another way to rework that array access such that it still works and such that Notepad++'s syntax highlighting will be happy?

Comment: [Quoting the wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1032): "In Tcl, everything is a string. Quoting strings is mostly not necessary - and can even be harmful, as in this example..." You can read the article to see how it can be harmful.

Comment: The "mostly" not necessary scares me slightly, but this gives me something to work with.

Comment: In this case, it's a variable you've quoted, not a string. So I'd say definitely not necessary.

Comment: The "mostly" does not indicate inconsistencies, but rather that a full discussion of the implications may be longish (there are, for instance, eight basic ways to dereference a variable name using combinations of dqoutes and braces, and one of them will fail because of a subtle interaction). The issue here is that Notepad++ treats double quotes as indicating a string literal, while in Tcl double quotes are used to "soft quote" strings (removing the syntactic effects of e.g. spaces and braces). So, yes, test it to see if it works, but if it does work you can be assured that it will always work.

Comment: That `info exists` will return false, as you've done a `set map [something]` immediately above, _guaranteeing_ that `map` is not an array…

Comment: @DonalFellows: good catch. Over-focussing on some detail is one of the programmer's worst enemies. The whole picture needs to be there all the time.

Comment: OK, I admit it, I removed a couple of dozen lines of setup code where the array is initialised, for the sake of making the illustration of the offending part of my code clearer. Edited to try to clarify that.

Comment: @ClickRick: the thing is that if your code first initializes `map` by using `set` to assign the result of a command to it, and later uses the form `map(...)` to reference an element, somewhere in between you will have had to discard the first `map` with `unset` and then reinitialized it using `array set`. That at least appears to be unsound coding practice.

Comment: How the array is created is irrelevant to my question. You may assume that it is created correctly, as the code has been in production for a number of years. The side-effects of it not working could be subtle, as there could be external code which relies on it, or on which this relies, so while I am grateful for the attention to this other small detail, it is irrelevant to my problem and @TrojanName's answer (below) is what I need.

Comment: @ClickRick: sure, the most important thing is that the code ultimately works. I'm just a little bit intrigued that you are worried about syntax highlighting but indifferent to the fact that the code being highlighted is written backwards :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Textpad and your proc looks good to me when I put in a TCL file.

What you could do is remove the double quotes around $type. They're not needed i.e.

change

```
if {[info exists map("$type")]} {    
        set frame $map("$type")
```

to

```
if {[info exists map($type)]} {    
        set frame $map($type)
```

Comment: "They're not needed" will need to be tested, specifically against other modules, legacy code elsewhere, customisations, persisted values, and the like, but I'm encouraged enough to try it. If it works out then I'll accept the answer, but if it doesn't then I'll hopefully have a refinement which I can add to the question.

Comment: Testing is always wise :)

Comment: @ClickRick: in this case, quotes are absolutely, unequivocally not needed.